# Change color of hover element?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the background color on an element when I hover on it, but i won't work!?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".walkingRoute-container").hover(function(){
    $("walkingRoute-container").css("background","#02baff");
  });
});
```

Preciate som help. Thanks!

Comment: please check your code. a dot(.) is lacking on $("walkingRoute-container")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the dot before the class name in the selector.

Use `$(this)` to target the element that is actually hovered, otherwise you will change the background of all elements with that class. You probably also want a function that removes the background when you leave the element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".walkingRoute-container").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background","#02baff");
  },function(){
    $(this).css("background","");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The dot was missing!

This element are inside a link tag, and I wonder how will I change or add the code to let the background color change and keep that color if I click on it to highligt that this element?

Comment: @user637364 i think you should show appreciation by acceping answer

Comment: @user637364: You could use the click event on the link tag to set the background on the link tag. That way that element would keep it's background color even when the hover changes the background of the inner element.

Answer (score 2):

Should there be a . before the class name inside the funcion?

Answer (score 0):

`$("walkingRoute-container").css("background","#02baff");`

should be

`$(".walkingRoute-container").css("background","#02baff");`

Answer (score 0):

I removed my answer about jQuery because mortenDelfi, Clyde Lobo, Guffa and 3nigma has already said everything. I only want to point out that maybe you may achieve what you need in pure CSS with no JavaScript using :hover selector like this:

```
.walkingRoute-container:hover { background-color: #02baff }
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f5VN8/).